# Необычное придаточное без подчинительного союза

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

*Люди всегда узнают шутку, смеялись они над ней или нет.*

Верно ли, что это не БСП, а неполное СПП с пропущенным уступительным союзом? Если так, то какой уступительный союз пропущен?

Я предполагаю, что пропущен союз «ли», но не уверен.

Люди всегда узнают шутку, смеялись *ли* они над ней или нет.

> Ли. Условно-уступительный союз (близок по знач. союзам если, ежели): ◆ Придёт ли ночь и мрак печальный, — идём к дороге столбовой. М. Ю. Лермонтов, «Преступник», 1829 г.

Answer (score 2):

Я полагаю, что предложение должно иметь такой вид:

***Люди всегда узнаЮт шутку, смеются ли  они над ней или нет.***

1) Это союз ***ЛИ...ИЛИ*** с пропущенной частицей ЛИ в упрощенном (разговорном) варианте. Этот союз у Розенталя определяется как **сочинительный, разделительный,** неповторяющийся (для однородных членов) и повторяющийся (для простых предложений в составе сложного).

2) Но вот отношения между частями предложения здесь явно **уступительного** характера, содержание можно пересказать так: Люди всегда узнаЮт шутку, хотя реагируют на нее по-разному (даже если они реагируют на нее по-разному).

3) Однако это семантика, а как насчет **грамматики?** Уступительные отношения могут быть выражены в различных сложных предложениях (ССП, СПП, БСП).

Вот пример. (1) Было ли это на самом деле или нет? (2) Я не знаю, было ли это на самом деле или нет.

Предложение (2) — это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным? **А где здесь изъяснительный союз?**  Вроде бы частица ЛИ вместо него, да только это условное понимание. На самом-то дел нет здесь подчинительного союза,  а изъяснительные отношения может выразить и БСП.

4) **А если это будут не изъяснительные отношения, а другие.** Например, в таком предложении: *Затевались ли в городе свадьбы, или кто весело справлял именины, Пётр Михайлыч **всегда** с удовольствием рассказывал об этом* (Пис);

Это как раз **уступительные отношения обобщающего характера**. Они строятся по такой схеме: *Что бы ни происходило, Пётр Михайлыч **всегда** с удовольствием рассказывал об этом.*

5) И заданное предложение строится так же, они очень похожи. И так же возникает вопрос **о пропущенном подчинительном союзе**: если его нет, то это уже бессоюзное предложение?

6) Тогда делаем вывод: **Это БСП со значением уступки,** вторая часть содержит однородные члены, связанные сочинительным союзом ЛИ...ИЛИ (ЛИ пропущено в разговорном варианте).

7) **А эта информация вызывает сомнения:**

Ли. Условно-уступительный союз (близок по знач. союзам если, ежели): ◆ Придёт ли ночь и мрак печальный, — идём к дороге столбовой. М. Ю. Лермонтов, «Преступник», 1829 г [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/ли](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8)

В этом примере **нет значения уступки, только условное значение** (если придет...). Для выражения уступки нужен повторяющийся союз ЛИ...ИЛИ, который вместе со структурным наречием ***всегда*** может выразить обобщающее значение в БСП.

Comment: Не решусь поправить, но в предпоследней строке второго пункта Вы случайно забыли дефис в первом наречии „по-разному”.

Comment: Спасибо, в таких случаях править можно.

Comment: А почему предложение сразу становится БСП при отсутствии союза? Он же там явно подразумевается. И вы говорите: "Это союз ЛИ...ИЛИ с пропущенной частицей ЛИ в упрощенном (разговорном) варианте". Чем вам не нравится версия про неполное СПП?

Comment: А как вам нравится такое высказывание: все БСП можно считать СПП или ССП с пропущенными союзами. В конце концов, они же ясно подразумеваются. К чему вообще возиться с этими БСП, тире и двоеточие  ставить. Так нет же, ставят. Считают, что интонация становится главным средством связи, если союза нет. Считают.что это совсем другая грамматическая форма. Это я объясняю, чем мне не нравится версия про неполное СПП.

Comment: А частицу ЛИ часто пропускают, например: Я не знаю, видел (ли) он или нет. Обычно полный союз ЛИ...ИЛИ  используется в книжной речи.